# Drawing XY graph in C# -  Win CE 5.0 (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am new to windows CE and I am developing a dialog application in which I have to plot a XY graph. Searched in Internet couldn't get anything useful. It would be great if some one helps me in finding a simple graph library which I can use in my c# program to draw a graph

Answer (score 0):

These might meet your criteria, they are native C#. Not sure they suppoert CE though.

The default Chart component included with .NET;
http://codeabout.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/easy-way-to-plot-graphs-in-c-and-visual-studio-2010/

Two altenartives
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32836/A-simple-C-library-for-graph-plotting
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/